# Deletion of elements in array with $timeout does not work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The directive notification should delete "itself" after 5 seconds. However some elements get missed and some get deleted more than once. Identifier property is unique for each notification. Thanks for help.

Factory

```
angular.module('AdS').factory('notificationFactory', function () {
var notificationFactory = {};
notificationFactory.notifications = [];
notificationFactory.identifier =0;
notificationFactory.add = function(note){
    if(typeof note!=='undefined'){
        notificationFactory.identifier++;
        note.identifier = notificationFactory.identifier;
        notificationFactory.notifications.push(note);
    }

}
notificationFactory.delete = function (note) {
    if(typeof note!=='undefined'){     
        for(var i =0;i<notificationFactory.notifications.length;i++){
            if(notificationFactory.notifications[i].identifier==note.identifier){
                notificationFactory.notifications.splice(i,1);

            }
        }
    }

     return "";
}

notificationFactory.getNotifications = function () {
    return notificationFactory.notifications;
}

return notificationFactory;
});
```

Directive

```
angular.module('AdS').directive('siteNotification', [
'$timeout',
function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restric: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/htmlBits/notification.html",
        scope: {

            note:"=",
            center:"="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {  
        $timeout(function () {           
                scope.center.delete(scope.note);

            }, 5000);



            scope.delete=function(note){

                scope.center.delete(note);
            }



        }
    };
}

]);
```

html

```
 <site-notification ng-repeat="not in notificationCenter.notifications track by $index" center=notificationCenter note=not ></site-notification>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an array for `notificationFactory.notifications`, you could use an object, with the unique identifier pointing to your note like so:

```
notificationFactory.notifications = {};
notificationFactory.add = function(note) {
    if (typeof note!=='undefined') {
        notificationFactory.identifier++;
        notificationFactory.notifications[notificationFactory.identifier] = note;
    }
}

notificationFactory.delete = function (note) {
    if(typeof note!=='undefined'){     
        notificationFactory.notifications[notificationFactory.identifier] = null;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Also, in your directive, you seem to be injecting notificationFactory via the html. This is very unusual, the typical way to inject your factory is as follows:

```
angular.module('AdS').directive('siteNotification', [
    '$timeout',
    'notificationFactory',
    function ($timeout, notificationFactory) {
        ...
    }
```

The only reason I can see to do it differently way is if you want to be able to inject a different type of factory into your directive.

Comment: Adding a notification to the array as  notificationFactory.notifications.[notificationFactory.identifier] = note - worked. Thanks mate.

Comment: Although actually realised I have a typo... Glad to know that it worked, but I'm still updating the answer.